# Definition of "theilhaft" and "Myops"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not finding it's meaning anywhere. It is a piece of Schopenhauer's Essay Über die Weiber, which is a quite mysoginistic one by the way.
Here is the context in which the word is found:

> Je edler und vollkommener eine Sache ist, desto später und langsamer gelangt sie zur Reife. Der Mann erlangt die Reife seiner Vernunft und Geisteskräfte kaum vor dem acht und zwanzigsten Jahre; das Weib mit dem achtzehnten. Aber es ist auch eine Vernunft danach: eine gar knapp gemessene. Daher bleiben die Weiber ihr Leben lang Kinder, sehn immer nur das Nächste, kleben an der Gegenwart, nehmen den Schein der Dinge für die Sache und ziehn Kleinigkeiten den wichtigen Angelegenheiten vor. Die Vernunft nämlich ist es, vermöge deren der Mensch nicht, wie das Thier, bloß in der Gegenwart lebt, sondern Vergangenheit und Zukunft übersieht und bedenkt; woraus dann seine Vorsicht, seine Sorge und häufige Beklommenheit entspringt. Der Vortheile, wie der Nachtheile, die Dies bringt, ist das Weib, in Folge seiner schwächern Vernunft, weniger **theilhaft**: vielmehr ist dasselbe ein geistiger **Myops**, indem sein intuitiver Verstand in der Nähe scharf sieht, hingegen einen engen Gesichtskreis hat, in welchen das Entfernte nicht fällt; daher eben alles Abwesende, Vergangene, Künftige, viel schwächer auf die Weiber wirkt, als auf uns.

Also, I would like to know what "Myops" means, and what it's genre is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

der *Myops*, eigentlich *Myope* ist ein *Kurzsichtiger* (vgl. Myopie = Kurzsichtigkeit)

*etwas teilhaft sein* = *an etwas teilhaben?* Das Wort ist veraltet.

Somit bedeutet der Teilsatz etwa:

> Daran (der Vernunft) haben Frauen weniger Anteil und deswegen sind deren Vor- und Nachteile schwächer ausgeprägt: Sie sind mental *kurzsichtig* (auf die das Naheliegende fixiert), weil sie unvernünftig sind.

Für jemanden, der womöglich gerade beklagt, dass er ständig mit dem Kopf in den Wolken schwebt (*sich mit den wichtigen Problemen beschäftigt*) und deswegen seinen Haushalt nicht führen kann, wirkt Schopenhauer ernsthaft beleidigend.

Comment: Ja, wirklich habe ich nicht bemerkt, dass *Myops* konnte *Kurzsichtigkeit* bedeuten. Dennoch könnte ich keine modernere Version dieses Textes im Internet finden, weil alle die neuere Versionen haben die Schreibung nur ein kleines bisschen geändert, z.B *Teil* anstatt *Theil*, oder *sehen* anstatt *sehn*...

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa: Außer einer manchmal etwas veralteten Rechtschreibung ist der Text in modernem Deutsch geschrieben. Eine "Übersetzung".würde den Text in keiner Weise besser oder verständlicher machen.

Answer (score 2):

"theilhaft" refers to "Teil haben," or taking part in something.

"Myop" refers myopia, but in the context of "mental myopia," it would mean "tunnel vision."

The whole (misogynistic) passage alleges that women have weaker reason, and therefore can't participate fully in thoughts that deal with remote points in time like the past or future.

Answer (score 2):

Myops is Greek μύωψ "shortsighted". In Greek it is an adjective and can be either masculine or feminine, but Schopenhauer is using it as a masculine noun.

Answer (score 1):

*»Myops«* has been handled, just want to add some information about *»theilhaft«*:

> **theilhaft** = old spelling for **teilhaft**
> **teilhaft** = rare alternative for **teilhaftig¹**
> **[einer Sache teilhaftig werden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/teilhaftig)** = in den Besitz oder Genuss einer Sache gelangen
> **[einer Sache teilhaftig sein](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/teilhaftig)** = in den Besitz oder Genuss einer Sache gelangt sein

So

> Der Vortheile, wie der Nachtheile, (...) ist das Weib weniger
> theilhaft.

means:

> Die Frau ist in geringerem Grad in den Besitz der Vor- und Nachteile
> gelangt.

or simpler:

> Die Frau kennt die Vor- und Nachteile schlechter.

<sub>¹Source: DUDEN - Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (2000)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

"Der Vortheile, wie der Nachtheile, die Dies bringt, ist das Weib, in Folge seiner schwächern Vernunft, weniger theilhaft"

What he's saying is that a woman doesn't understand it to the same extent as a man, apparently because of her inferior mental capacity. I'm trying to think of a direct English translation, but I'm struggling. Literally, it means something like "she takes less part" in the (dis)advantages.

As has been stated before, "Myops" seems to be a paraphrase for near-sightedness. I'm German and I haven't seen this used before, it's the English word "myopic" that makes me think so.

In any way, the misogyny on display here is difficult to swallow.